# download big data from sql server to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sql-server, sqlite, bigdata

My boss asked me to develop an order system for our company's salesmen. Our company has almost 100,000 items to sale. In order to improve the performance, we will ask salesmen to download all data from sql server to iPhone local sqllite one time per week, and build index.

I'm a windows mobile developer, and it's very easy to use RDA to download data from sql server to local sqlce. The size in windows mobile device is about 20M.Now I need to do the same thing in iPhone.

I'm a newbie at iPhone development. Please give me some ideas about this project.Any input will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some information on using SQLite in iOS: [iOS offline data storage tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891031/ios-offline-data-storage-tutorial)

You'll probably need to export the DB as SQL and download it from the server, then import the SQL into SQLite.

As another answerer suggested, you could expose a REST interface on the server--assuming your server is setup to export the contents of the entire product database.  Then there are any number of third party tools for importing JSON data (eg: via REST) into CoreData.  Or if your REST data isn't too complicated it's not hard to parse it and directly add it to CoreData.

I personally recommend CoreData rather than using sqlite directly--iOS makes it very easy to do so.  But it's also a matter of personal choice and I know lots of people prefer to use sqlite directly (especially if they want to build some cross-platform code, eg: to make an Android version which shares the same DB schema and logic).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably many ways to do this, but I would go with build a rest api for the server data. Then on the iPhone side of things, make a network call to access the data.